# If I know specific pair of characters that model confuses in OCR task how can I fixe it?

Tags: computer-vision, train, transformers, optical-character-recognition

I train OCR model to recognize cyrillic handwritten text. I know, for example, that it confuses very often 'Б' with '6'. How can I use this information to fine tune the model ?

Just in case, my architecture is resnet50 + transformer

UPD: train data is crops with one or two words (sequence of characters). Overall my model is able to predict 82 characters.

Comment: Are you testing just on a single character?

Comment: @GoodLuck thanks, I've specified information in the question.

Comment: Can you provide architecture details and the idea how the model works/ learns.

Comment: @GoodLuck I use resnet50 to get features and then I split it into vectors and pass it to encoder/decoder. [diagram](https://sun9-33.userapi.com/impg/l7bDgXLob9f6FVo_hrM30oFmCarKaYVa-gT4bQ/_tkAY9aKVe8.jpg?size=872x350&quality=96&sign=3cf8402303818912e5818f14f2ec7a06&type=album)

Comment: [whole pipeline](https://sun9-69.userapi.com/impg/HzW_f0_xCZTIxCnPzvJsVbGQ_1v3f7DFxXfQxg/S3aAkW_R3g8.jpg?size=859x591&quality=96&sign=e14352a6af90059cdf2e99db95a7d14b&type=album)